# How should I troubleshoot Wi-fi timeout issues?

Tags: wifi, airport, macos

I am having some Wi-fi issues at home and am looking for some advice on how to troubleshoot it.

**The setup.** 
Comcast Modem connected to Airport Extreme Basestation which has a NAS drive and MacMini hardwired to, and my Macbook Pro which connects via Wi-fi.

**The problem.** 
My internet will work for a couple minutes to 10 minutes and then I start getting lots of timeout errors.

**Things I have tried.** 
My laptop's Wi-fi works perfectly all day at the office. 
Hardwiring my laptop into the Comcast Modem internet works fine. 
Unplugging the Basestation from the modem local network works fine, (swapped some filed around between machines)

Anyone have any ideas what is going on? Or what else I should be checking?

Comment: Do you get a stable and lasting connection to the LAN and internet when connecting your MacBook Pro to the AirPort via ethernet cable?

Comment: What OS are you using? 10.7.0 seems to have some wifi timeout issues on some set ups.

Comment: Do you have another wifi router you could try temporarily to see if you have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS you are using but I would suggest looking at the LAN to see if there is any WiFi channel or address conflict with your en1 connection (Mac mini airport or NAS?); also check that the AP has a channel that does not conflict with a nearby neighbor and is at least 2 channels away from its nearest competitor (if AP is 6, any neighbors should be 8 or 4). After that, try deleting your connection on the laptop and adding the AP and network info including the DNS. 
You might also check that your LAN AP is the first in line in preferred networks and that there is no other Bluetooth, FireWire, etc. network enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that your internet connection drops out (but you're still connected properly to the Airport) - or that your connection to the Airport drops out?

In the former case: speak with your ISP.  Could be a modem issue or a much likelier option, a DNS problem.

In the latter: How far away are you?  Measure the signal strength with a tool like iStumbler.  How many walls does the signal have to pass through?  Export the Airport settings, wipe the device and restore the settings.

Comment: connection to my Airport is strong, as mentioned in the OP i am able to do stuff on my local network just fine.

also the modem itself seems to be ok, as when i plug directly into the modem my interent works just fine.